# This/that way, or in this/that way?

Tags: phrase-usage

Is 'This/that way' a colloquial way of saying 'In this/that way?'. 'In this/that way' to me sounds close to mean 'By doing so.' Does 'this/that way' mean the same thing, only more conversational?

Ex: You need to deposit the money in your bank account. This way, you stay away from overdrawing your account when using your debit card.
(conversational)

... In this way, you stay away... (more standard/grammatically correct)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Excluding theological works, **in this way** is normally used at the end of a sentence, meaning **[thus](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thus)** or **like this**, for example:

> Now one asks: what if everyone followed this maxim or acted **in this way**? - *[Rethinking Ethics in the Midst of Violence: A Feminist Approach to Freedom](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=kUaZq9Uvmb8C&pg=PA130&dq=%22in%20this%20way%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2i4T01s_ZAhWFn5QKHUjSDPQQ6AEISzAG#v=onepage&q=%22in%20this%20way%22&f=false)*

**this way** at the start of a sentence means **[thereby](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thereby)** or **by doing so** or **in that case**.

> But what if we knew the ending and it guaranteed our happiness? **That way**, no matter how bad things seemed at the time, we knew that everything would turn out okay. *[The mustard seed way](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=OAglUDp9EEcC&pg=PA63&dq=%22that%20way%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifktTn2s_ZAhVCpZQKHQU6BgE4ChDoAQhbMAk#v=onepage&q=%22that%20way%22&f=false)*

**in this way** is certainly quite formal, but the informal version of it is **like this**, and not **this way**.

Comment: During dehydration, most of the nutrients are concentrated in the remaining solids. **In this way**, dried fruits have more nutrients by weight than fresh fruits.  _Nutrition for life_

Comment: "You are going the wrong way" or "you are going on the wrong way". Please explain, sir.

Comment: @Kumarsadhu: That's a different meaning of **way**. The first is correct, the second is not. If you want more information, please ask a new question.

Comment: This reads fine to me as well: **In that way*, no matter how bad things seemed at the time, we knew that everything would turn out okay.*